# width and height doesnt change after rotating the screen in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am working on a RN app and I have an issue regarding the rotation and dimensions of the screen. I have a gallery application where I show three images in a row if the screen is vertical. I adjust it by dividing the width by the size of the image, I think this way of specifying the number of images in a row makes it consistent and changeable for different devices. However, after I rotate the screen, I was expecting to see more images in a row, but I didn't. I realized the width didn't change, so I saw three images again instead of 5 or 6. I am not sure if the way I am doing this is right or wrong. Any suggestions regarding this?? Also, how can I change the width and height dynamically, so that I can change the aligning of my gallery after rotation?
here is a part of my code

```
...var {height, width} = Dimensions.get('window');
var imageSize = 120;
// number : number of images in a row
var number = Math.round(width/imageSize);
console.log(number);
var CameraRollView = React.createClass({

propTypes: propTypes,

getDefaultProps: function(): Object {
    return {
        groupTypes: 'SavedPhotos',
        batchSize: 5,
        imagesPerRow: number,
        assetType: 'Photos',
        renderImage: function(asset) {
            //var imageSize = 120;
            var imageStyle = [styles.image, {width: imageSize, height: imageSize}];
            return (
                <TouchableHighlight onPress={
                    ()=>{
                        /**fire gallery action selectImage*/
                        this.selectImage(asset.node.image.uri, this.images);
                    }
                }  key={asset.node.image.uri}>
                    <Image
                        source={asset.node.image}
                        style={imageStyle}
                    />
                </TouchableHighlight>
            );
        },
    };
},
...
```

here what important is -imagesPerRow- I want it to be dynamic, as I rotate the device.

Comment: use setstate to update whenever the view rerenders https://reactnative.dev/docs/dimensions

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend against using the `Dimensions` module if you need to respond to screen size changes.

The [`View`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/view.html) component provides an `onLayout` property that is called each time that View's layout has to be recalculated (e.g. on device rotation). I don't know anything about the architecture of your app, so I will just say the easiest way to use it in my opinion is to set it to a function on the root `View` in your app that writes the new parameters to state (or to your flux/redux stores if you use that).

You can then pass that information through your app and use it as you see fit.

Comment: thanks for sharing your opinion, ill try it hopefully it works